# Passing data between tableviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, tableview

I have multiple uitableviews. I need to pass selections from these tableviews to the other tableview.

How can I do this task ?

Thanks

Comment: are d 2 tables in same viewController..?

Comment: Yes, in the same. Multiple tableviews created by using a loop.

Comment: Any particular reason for having three TableViews in one ViewController?  It's a lot easier to manage when they are in separate viewControllers.

Comment: u can have instance of NSIndexPath in ur interface, & set the value from `didSelectRow` or you can pass the indexPath from the `didSelectRow` method to your next function which requires it...

Comment: Just have 3 variables and set them as selection occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would have separate UITableViewControllers in each one.

If you are using storyboards then do this in prepareForSegue if you are not using storyBoards then do this after you have alloc - initWithNibName for the TVC you are about to push.

In the new TableViewController set a variable for the information you want to pass in...

```
@property NSString *selectedName;
```

And then in the VC that the first table is in set this value before pushing it.

i.e.

With Storyboard...

```
nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

nextViewController.selectedName = @"blah";
```

of without storyboards....

```
nextViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

nextViewController.selectedName = @"blah";

[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

This is the best way of doing this.